# Can't switch between KDE/Gnome

Tags: centos, gnome, kde

I was using KDE desktop on my Centos7. Lately I have installed Gnome. I was expecting I can switch between KDE/Gnome at system logon, but I dont have any selection:

[image]

Now it always starts Gnome, how to get back KDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot is of the username prompt. You should have the option to switch once you get to the password prompt.